# R - get frequency table of n-grams

Tags: r, frequency, n-gram

I want to calculate a frequency table of ngrams in R.

Input is a sequence with 10 elements like

ABC A HDA ASD ABC A UZF FJ UZF FJ

Using the R package ngrams I already got the distinct ngrams (e.g. n=2). But now I want to count the occurences of each ngram and here I struggle. I started with grep to search each ngram in the original sequence but it's quite slow with a high number of elements.

Does anybody know a better way to generate a frequency table of ngrams in R?

Thanks!

Comment: Try it out with the steps described here: http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/39014_76f8487a8fb84ed7849e96846847c295.html

Comment: Do you mean token ngrams, such as "A HDA", or character ngrams? And you want only adjacent pairs? Provide specifics and I can show you a fast way to do this in R.